# Hermitian/Skew Hermitian Matrix for non-orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthonormal, hermitian-matrices

Assume that the matrix $A$ is Hermitian/skew-Hermitian. There is a theorem, which says that if this matrix represents some transformation $T$ with respect to an orthonormal basis, then this transformation itself is Hermitian/skew-Hermitian.

What happens if the basis of the representation of $A$ is NOT orthonormal?

The theorem I know does not hold. However, can we still call such a matrix Hermitian/skew-Hermitian since it does not imply that the transformation it represents is the same type (Hermitian/skew-Hermitian)? And if so, does it have any uses?

Comment: A matrix has its own independent existence, irrespective of any basis and/or linear transformation. Hermitian, for a matrix, is defined without regard to basis or transformation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, idk, Apostol introduces matrices as representations for linear transformations. so I have been trying to always connect any operation on matrices to some operation on linear transformations. But then a Hermitian matrix does no have as much sense, since it cannot be diagonalised? If we diagonalise, it means we assume the standard basis, right?

Comment: To diagonalize a matrix $A$ is to find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix. No mention there of any basis, standard or otherwise. Diagonalization can be interpreted in terms of bases and transformations, but it can be defined (as I have done) without reference to those concepts.

Comment: When you write a matrix $S$ it is assumed in the canonic basis or Identity, as $ISI$. The changement of basis of a matrix is the matrix $P^{-1}SP$ which does not need to be Symmetric or Skew-Symmetric unless $P$ is unitary (orthonormal basis) so $P^*=P^{-1}$.

Comment: If you want the definition of "Hermitian linear operator" to agree with "Hermitian matrix", then you must be using an orthonormal basis of the underlying vector space. If you are using some basis which is not orthonormal, then a Hermitian linear operator may be mapped to a non-Hermitian matrix, and vice-versa.

Comment: @Joppy, thx for this clarification! So in theory it means we can have a non-matching Hermitian operators and Hermitian matrices. This is the gist of my question.